# Agora Security Token Generation (Golang)

Tags: security, go, privileges, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Looking at Token generation of Agora (https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/token_server_nodejs?platform=Node.js).

We are required to provide role of the user when generating a token. In the Go API there are 4 role definition: attendee, publisher, subscriber, and admin.

How do the tokens differ if they are generated using any one of the 4 roles? How does attendee differ from a subscriber, how does publisher differ from an admin?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Role` you are referring to is an arbitrary struct created to establish an example hierarchy of possible user roles that could be used to set privileges.

If you look at the Agora Token Builder ([Golang example](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/go/src/RtcTokenBuilder/RtcTokenBuilder.go)), on [Line 42](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/417ef2a496553bbb57e5f77b7734468387b09e4d/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/go/src/RtcTokenBuilder/RtcTokenBuilder.go#L42) it uses the Role to assign a set of privileges.

```golang
    if (role == RoleAttendee) || (role == RolePublisher) || (role == RoleAdmin) {
        token.AddPrivilege(accesstoken.KPublishVideoStream, privilegeExpiredTs)
        token.AddPrivilege(accesstoken.KPublishAudioStream, privilegeExpiredTs)
        token.AddPrivilege(accesstoken.KPublishDataStream, privilegeExpiredTs)
    }
```

In the code, each role gets the same privileges (*which is generally useless in a production environment*) so you need to update the code to have whatever user roles you'd like in order to set the appropriate privileges for that token.

The privileges set here are meant to let the Agora backend know what actions the user can perform in the channel, ranging from the fundamental `joinCahnnel` to `publishStream` to `publishVideoCdn`.

Available privileges:

```
type Privileges uint16

const (
    KJoinChannel        = 1
    KPublishAudioStream = 2
    KPublishVideoStream = 3
    KPublishDataStream  = 4

    KPublishAudiocdn           = 5
    KPublishVideoCdn           = 6
    KRequestPublishAudioStream = 7
    KRequestPublishVideoStream = 8
    KRequestPublishDataStream  = 9
    KInvitePublishAudioStream  = 10
    KInvitePublishVideoStream  = 11
    KInvitePublishDataStream   = 12

    KAdministrateChannel = 101
    KLoginRtm            = 1000
)
```

> **NOTE:** token priveleges are not enforced by default, so you will have to file a Jira ticket (https://agora-ticket.agora.io) to make the request to enable it on your account.

Comment: Thank you! So RtcTokenBuilder.go in src directory is really meant to be an example of how to use AccessToken.go? Maybe you ought to move it to the example directory instead.

Comment: Its meant to be a basic but functional example of how to build the token server, so Im not sure if it will be changed in that way, but in general tokens are very important and I will speak with the team internally so we can improve this process so there is less confusion in the future.

Comment: @JoeLin, I misspoke ... the role.attendee is a legacy role that was previously used similarly to a publisher/admin role. On Line 32 of the Golang example it recommends using 2 roles, subscriber and publisher. The subscriber can only join the channel, and the publisher is the one that get all the roles outlined above.